# Is there a Central Search in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, modern-experience, sharepoint-search

In our Dev environment, I can see the search results by default go to a page within the site I did the search, for example:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/search.aspx
```

Now, in the client environment they have a different site for the the search results:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/search/Pages/results.aspx
```

This site was created even before we migrated the SP 2013 On-Prem to Online. It was configured in the OnPrem to search in the cloud.

So I was thinking I could create a Search Site from a kind of Search Site template, and then associate the search results to it from the sites I want.

I looked for that in SharePoint Admin but could not find any Search Site template.

Maybe it needs to be created from Office 365 Admin center?

Comment: Try hitting this URL in browser to check if the search site collection is created in your tenant or not: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/search`. Also check [this](https://kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/SharePoint-Search-Center.htm) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-center). let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ha, the site was already there. I can't believe I didn't try the url before asking... I realized my custom theme was not present there... The links are awesome. Thanks

Comment: Welcome, does this solves your issue? If yes, I will write it as an answer below.

Comment: yes, it did solve.

Comment: Great, glad it solved your issue. I have added it as an answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, there will be a search site collection created. URL of the site collection is in below format. Try hitting this URL in browser tab:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/search
```

Also check below documentations which will help you to configure search:

1. [Custom Search Center](https://kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/SharePoint-Search-Center.htm)
2. [Manage the Search Center in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-center)

Comment: nailed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing modern search results page in your site that exists at this url:

```
https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursitename/_layouts/15/search.aspx?q=hello
```

You can redirect users to this page and replacing the q query param with the actual term you want them to search for.

For example, if you want them to search for people instead, you will use this:

```
https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursitename/_layouts/15/search.aspx/people?q=Jose
```

Each tab in that page corresponds to a specific URL that you can use.